# When did David Hamelech become king?

Tags: malchut-royalty, king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul

The story of David in short, as requested:

- Shmuel (Samuel) anoints Shaul (Saul) king of Israel at G-d's command. ([Shmuel I 10:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15839#v=1) and [ibid. v 24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15839#v=24))
- Shaul disobeys G-d, and G-d regrets his anointment. ([Shmuel I 15:35](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15844#v=35) and [ibid. 16:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15845#v=1)
- Shmuel anoints David as King. ([Shmuel I 16:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15845#v=13))
- David serves in Shaul's court ([Shmuel I 16:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15845#v=21))
- David and Shaul have a falling out, and David flees.
- Shaul is killed by the Plishtim in battle. ([Shmuel I 31:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15860#v=6))
- Ishboshes becomes king, rules over 11 tribes while David rules Yehuda (Judah). ([Shmuel II 2:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15862#v=10))
- Ishboshes is killed by his generals. ([Shmuel II 4:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15864#v=7))
- David is accepted by all of Israel ([Shmuel II 5:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15865#v=3))

We know from the Gemara ([Brachos 48b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=48b&format=pdf)) that "one kingdom cannot overlap another by a hairsbreadth".
So when did David become King? When G-d regretted that He had made Shaul king? At David's anointment? When Shaul died? When Ishboshes was killed?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13092/5

Comment: I thought judaism is based on revelation to the whole nation. Samuel anointed Dave privately and the rest of Israelites must "know" that he is a legitimate king?

Comment: @JimThio You're confusing two very different things. Judaism is based on the mass revelation at Sinai, yes. That doesn't mean that every subsequent communication from G-d must be via mass revelation. That's why there are prophets, to further communicate the word of the G-d that we heard at Sinai. David's authority was established by the prophet Shmuel, and was not a secret.

Comment: The idea that judaism is based on mass revelation comes from the idea that if it were not,  A can say God told me that I shall be king. If it's private anyway, anyone can say God told me that I shall be king. In fact, every civil war in theocracy is based on different opinion on who God wants to be king

Comment: A complete lecture dedicated to this topic: https://www.etzion.org.il/he/tanakh/neviim/sefer-shmuel-bet/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93

Answer (score 11, accepted):

David's status after his anointing and before Shaul's death was actually, according to [Megillah 14b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=14b&format=pdf), the subject of a halachic dispute between him and Avigayil. David himself held that he was a king for all purposes, and that therefore Naval (who had denied his men food and insulted him - [I Sam. 25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15854)) was a rebel against the monarchy and could be put to death without trial. Avigayil countered that this is incorrect, because "Shaul is still alive and טבעך has not yet spread out in the world," and David conceded the point.

(The Soncino translation renders טבעך as "your fame," but Rambam ([Hil. Gezeilah 5:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/b305.htm#18)) - apparently based on this Gemara (see [Beur HaGra, Choshen Mishpat 369:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14400&pgnum=482)) - understands it to mean "coinage." He thus draws a distinction between a king whose coinage circulates, demonstrating that the people accept him as a legitimate ruler, and one who does not enjoy this confidence. David, then, was in the latter category during this period.)

After Shaul's death, David was indeed a king, just that at first he ruled only the tribe of Yehudah ([II Sam. 2:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15862#v=4)), with Ish Boshes ruling over the other tribes for part or all of this period (see commentaries ibid. 2:10-11). We find that the later kings of Yisrael vs. Yehudah were considered coequal for halachic purposes (Yerushalmi, Horios 3:2), so presumably the same would have applied to David and Ish Boshes: each was a king within his own sphere of influence (thus not violating the rule about "one kingship overlapping the other"). At any rate, the seven and a half years before the rest of the tribes accepted David as king are counted towards the total length of his reign ([II Sam. 5:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15865#v=5) and [I Kings 2:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15886#v=11)).

Comment: Political scientists like to distinguish between government *de jure* (on the books) and government *de facto* (facts on the ground); Rambam's currency argument establishes *de facto*. So after annointing he was king *de jure*, but not *de facto*.

Comment: What about the fact that anointing a king must be done with the presence of the Sanhedrin, as Malbim points out at David's third anointing, which implies that he was *not* halachically a king until then?

Comment: @jake: maybe indeed that's required only for someone who will be ruling the entire people? We see that the *zekeinim* aren't mentioned in connection with Ish Boshes' appointment either (nor, for that matter, Yeravam's, or Yehu's, or any of the other later kings).

Comment: Was Ish Boshes anointed? Certainly none of the later *malchei yisrael* were anointed with the *shemen hamishcha* (Yehu was anointed because of his rivalry with someone else (can't remember) and not even with the *shemen hamishcha*) which implies that none of them had the complete halachic status as kings anyway.

Comment: Everyone seems to agree that David was *chosen* to rule at Shmuel's anointing, and "accepted" as a ruler over each kingdom at its respective anointing, but when do the halachos of kings (such as *mored b'malchus*) kick in?

Comment: @jake: you're right, my mistake - no anointing is mentioned in connection with Ish Boshes, just that Avner "made him king." On your last point, though: that they didn't use the *shemen hamishchah* for the kings of Yisrael doesn't detract from their status as kings; it's simply that it's reserved for kings of the house of David (Rambam, Hil. Klei Hamikdash 1:7). Be that as it may, though, my point was that perhaps the whole ceremony - with anointing, the Sanhedrin, and (per Hil. Melachim 1:3) a navi - is needed only for a king over the whole nation.

Comment: @jake: hadn't seen your last comment earlier. That was precisely the argument between David and Avigayil, no? Later on we see that the halachos of mored b'malchus were applied (falsely, but in keeping with legal protocol) regarding Achav and Navos, which also demonstrates that they apply to a king over part of the nation - as Achav was, and as David was after Shaul's death.

Comment: @Alex, Interesting. It seems that David had a status of king halachically even while ruling over just Yehuda, like your comparison with Achav suggests. But before he was ruling over anyone, being just "anointed in advance" by Shmuel, then he was not sure if he had halachic king status, and this was his argument with Avigail

Comment: So Dave's argument that he is a king to Abigail is that he claimed that he is anointed by some old man in secret and that's it? Everyone has to believe he is king and pay tax? Also if he believe he is a king while Saul is still alive, how come he's not a rebel?

Answer (score 3):

What about the fact that it is possible that David was king of ONLY Judah for 2 years and then remained in Hevron but was king over all of Israel for 5.5 more years before moving to Jerusalem?

This seems like a likely idea given that Ish Boshet did not make a very good king and needed Avner to keep his kingship. If that is the case David became king 2 years after Shaul's death.

Comment: You mean king over all of Israel two years after Shaul's death. How would you like to explain Shmuel 2 5:5?

Comment: Oh, by the way, morah hochman, welcome to judaism.SE. Stick around and ask/answer more questions!

Comment: So in Shmuel 5.5 the math doesn't work. It tells us that David was king for 40 yrs. He was king in Hevron for 7.5yrs and in Jerusalem for 33yrs. Which is it 40yrs or 40.5yrs. The Rabbis teach that he was really king in Jerusalem for 32.5 yrs but in order to give honor to Jerusalem the number is rounded up in the text.

Comment: Yes, indeed. What I was referring to, though, was that the *pasuk* there specifies that David was king **over Yehuda** for 7.5 years in Chevron and over Israel for 33 years in Jerusalem. This does not seem to fit with your "possibility" that he ruled over Israel already 5.5 years before moving to Jerusalem.

Comment: @jake, actually, Malbim to II Sam. 2:10 suggests that indeed Ish Boshes ruled over eleven tribes for just two years, and then for the next five and a half years his kingdom gradually diminished - with more and more tribes or segments of tribes going over to David. So in a way, it's not completely incorrect to say that David ruled over more than Yehudah during that period.

Comment: The account of this story in the Book of Chronicles backs up the Malbim on this point.  Slowly after two years parts of Israel went to David, thus making him king over more and more of Israel, until Ish Boshet died when he became official king of all of Israel.